# Python: Creating a new interface in same frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to remove all the widgets from this frame and add new widgets. (To simulate the creation of a new interface inside the same frame.) I tried using:

```
frame.destroy()
```

and:

```
frame.grid_forget()
```

When I tried the first one, it closed the whole window. When I tried the second one, nothing happened. I am not using anything other than the grid layout in the tkinter package.

Comment: It's confusing since you use the name `frame` for a root window while `frame` is actually a `tkinter` widget.

Comment: please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to destroy the widgets within and not the frame itself.

```
    def remove_children():
        for widget in frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
```